# how can i read from a binary file?

Tags: java, file

I want to read a binary file that its size is `5.5 megabyte`(a mp3 file). I tried it with `fileinputstream` but it took many attempts. If possible, I want to read file with a minimal waste of time.

Comment: Of course it's possible. What's your specific problem? What does "it take many times" mean?

Comment: for example when i want to read that file it takes 5 minute that's not good.i want to read it in a less munutes

Comment: So it's not the network that is causing the slow read. Can we see your existing code?

Comment: i solve that.thanks my friend

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    InputStream i = new FileInputStream("a.mp3");
    byte[] contents = new byte[i.available()];
    i.read(contents);
    i.close();
}
```

**A more reliable version** based on helpful comment from @Paul Cager & Liv related to **available**'s and **read**'s unreliability.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    File f = new File("c:\\msdia80.dll");
    InputStream i = new FileInputStream(f);
    byte[] contents = new byte[(int) f.length()];

    int read;
    int pos = 0;
    while ((read = i.read(contents, pos, contents.length - pos)) >= 1)
    {
        pos += read;
    }
    i.close();
}
```

Comment: That is not safe code. InputStream.available() "Returns an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream without blocking by the next invocation of a method for this input stream."   That is not necessarily the same as the size of the file.

Comment: I'm really curious how the original approach looked like. :)

Comment: Agree with Paul Cager. In fact read(byte[] buffer) will not read up to the limit of buffer -- instead will read as many bytes as are available! So you could end up reading just a few bytes and not the whole file.

Comment: @Liv -- u are so right, so many things can go wrong. Seems u can't do it without a while if you want to be 100% sure -- updated answer.

Comment: One last comment -- the above won't work with huge files -- where f.length() returns a size bigger than Integer.MAX_VALUE -- but I'll let you off on that since @mehdi mentioned a few Mb only in size.

Comment: @Liv, for files greater than 2GB, you migh not be interested in storing that in memory anyhow. This can go on forever 32bit vs 64-bit a.s.o. Thanks for the pointers thought, upvoted u :)

Comment: yes i hear you -- though i've seen some rubbish code attempting to do that -- and failing due to the above (thank God!).

Answer (score 4):

You should try to use a BufferedInputStream around your FileInputStream. It will improve the performance significantly.

```
new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream, 8192 /* default buffer size */);
```

Furthermore, I'd recommend to use the read-method that takes a byte array and fills it instead of the plain read.

Comment: The default is 8192, perhaps you were thinking of 4096.

Answer (score 2):

There are useful utilities in [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) for reading a file at once.  This is simpler and efficient for modest files up to 100 MB.

```
byte[] bytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file); // handles IOException/close() etc.
```